# Dont know how to connect to remote with ssh via jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, ssh, pipeline

So Im doing a project which at the end I get a docker image that hold my python project

at the end of the Jenkins pipeline Im trying to connect to "production instance" on ec2 and pull&run the image(which is pushed to my docker hub).

```
stage('SSH Connection'){ 
    steps{ 
        withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'sshUser', keyFileVariable: 'SSH_PRIVATE_KEY')]) { 
            sh ''' ssh -i $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY ubuntu@18.207.220.81 echo 'lebron got swept'
            '''
        }
    }
}
```